# itext space out number in a comb field java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, adobe, itext7

[image]

How do I make sure that the number are spaced are correctly?

```
fields.get("Page2[0].Line68bCombField[0].f2_081[0]").setValue("123456789");
fields.get("Page2[0].Line68dCombField[0].f2_082[0]").setValue("123423423444");
```

Comment: Are you sure that your field is defined as a comb field (that is: that the *Comb* bit is set in the form flags `/Ff` value)? Also: the structure of the field name leads to believe that your form is an XFA form, yet your code shows that you assume an AcroForm. Are you sure you're dealing with an AcroForm?

Comment: I don't know if this is XFA or AcroForm. This is an external PDF. How do I know if its XFA? and If it is what changes do I need to make. Regarding the flags how do i know if flags are set?

Answer (score 2):

iText 7 did not (yet) support comb fields.
Support for comb fields has been added.
The functionality should soon be available in the snapshot builds.
The value can be set using the flag

```
PdfTextFormField.FF_COMB
```

Comment: I added 7 to your answer. iText 5 has been supporting comb fields for a long time.